# High CPU usage when editing build.gradle on Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, cpu

High CPU usage when viewing/editing build.gradle on Intellij Idea.
Is there an Intellj setting  that can make this stop?

Comment: Seems like this is a bug in IntelliJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109442